# sql query performance improvements

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization

I need to optimize a query. I have two tables:

- `tblcard` (`CardID int, SerialNumber varchar(15), clientID`)
- `tblTransaction` (`TransactionID int, SerialNumber Varchar(15), Transactiondate datetime, ...`)

I need to list for a date interval all cards that were involved in a transaction, client name and the date of first transaction for all the cards

Here is what I've done:

```
select 
   tra.serialNumber, 
   cli.clientName,
   (select top 1 tra.Transactiondate 
    from tblTransaction tra 
    where tra.SerialNumber = car.SerialNumber 
    order by tra.TransactionDate)
from 
   tblTransaction tra
left join 
   tblCard car on car.SerialNumber = tra.SerialNumber
left join 
   tblClient cli on car.ClientID = cli.ClientID
where 
   --date conditions
```

but given the fact that are very many transactions, this query runs very slow(more that 3 minutes). Do you have any idea on how to optimize this?

Comment: Please provide information about the used DBMS, existing indexes, a date condition example and an execution plan.

Comment: Information about the third table `tblClient` and an example output would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An execution plan would help. Out of the box, replacing `left` joins with `inner` joins might help if possible. And using a subquery is also an awful idea from performance viewpoint. Instead, you might want to use a view or a CTE:

```
with LatestTransactions (SerialNumber, TransactionDate)
as
(
  select
   SerialNumber, max(TransactionDate) as TransactionDate
  from tblTransaction
  group by SerialNumber
)
select 
 tra.serialNumber, 
 cli.clientName,
 lt.TransactionDate
from tblTransaction tra
left join LatestTransactions lt on lt.SerialNumber = tra.SerialNumber
left join tblCard car on car.SerialNumber = tra.SerialNumber
left join tblClient cli on car.ClientID = cli.ClientID
where 
   --date conditions
```

Of course, if you're not using the proper indices, it might not help much. That's why looking at the query execution plan is important. Where is the query spending time and why? Can you limit the dataset in a reasonable way? Would introducing a new index on some column help? Why are you joining on the serial number, which is a 15 char long string, instead of some identity column?

Answer (score 0):

Luaan, your answer is good, here is a more readable(in my opinion) answer (ingnore the missing of tblclient table)

```
select tblTransaction.TransactionDate, Mindate.SerialNumber, Mindate.TransactionDate 
from tblTransaction
outer apply (select MIN(tra.Transactiondate) TransactionDate, car.SerialNumber 
            from tblTransaction tra 
            INNER JOIN tblCard car on car.SerialNumber = tra.SerialNumber
            where car.SerialNumber = tblTransaction.SerialNumber group by car.SerialNumber) Mindate
where tblTransaction.TransactionDate between '2013-05-05' and '2014-05-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the subquery by an `DENSE_RANK` aggregation (oracle syntax):

```
select
   tra.serialNumber, 
   cli.clientName,
   MIN(tra.Transactiondate)
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY tra.TransactionDate)
       OVER (PARTITION BY tra.SerialNumber) AS transactiondate
from 
   tblTransaction tra
left join 
   tblCard car on car.SerialNumber = tra.SerialNumber
left join 
   tblClient cli on car.ClientID = cli.ClientID
where 
   --date conditions
```

Maybe some indexes are missed. The execution plan could clarify that.